# Trouble displaying SQL AJAX call results from jQuery onto HTML

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, mysqli

I am currently trying to display data returned from my database onto my php display page. I have been following along this tutorial:
https://www.phpzag.com/ajax-drop-down-selection-data-load-with-php-mysql/

At first I tried it to test against my data. But I found it to be working incorrectly. So I then decided to use the sample data provided in the tutorial on my system to see where things are going wrong. Thus my pages are as follows:

populatePage.php <---This acts as my "index.php" from tutorial

```
<?php
require_once('../../config/sessionHandler.php'); 
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="src/populatePage.js"></script>

    <title>Populate Page</title>
</head>
<body >
    <div class="page-header">
        <h3>
            <select id="employee">
                <option value="" selected="selected">Select Employee Name</option>
                    <?php
                    $sql = "SELECT id, employee_name, employee_salary, employee_age FROM employee LIMIT 10";
                    $resultset = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("database error:". mysqli_error($conn));
                    while( $rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultset) ) {
                    ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $rows["id"]; ?>"><?php echo $rows["employee_name"]; ?></option>
                    <?php } ?>
            </select>
        </h3>
    </div>
    <div id="display">
        <div id="heading" class="row">
            <h3>

            </h3>
        </div>
        <div id="records" class="row">
            <h3>

            </h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

populatePage.js <---My renamed version of getData.js from tutorial

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// code to get all records from table via select box
$("#employee").change(function() {
var id = $(this).find(":selected").val();
var dataString = 'empid='+ id;
$.ajax({
url: 'popJax.php',
dataType: "json",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(employeeData) {
if(employeeData) {
$("#heading").show();
$("#no_records").hide();
$("#emp_name").text(employeeData.employee_name);
$("#emp_age").text(employeeData.employee_age);
$("#emp_salary").text(employeeData.employee_salary);
$("#records").show();
} else {
$("#heading").hide();
$("#records").hide();
$("#no_records").show();
}
}
});
})
});
```

popJax.php <--- This is my getEmployee.php from the tutorial

```
<?php
require_once('../../config/sessionHandler.php');

$_SESSION['PopulateWorking'] = true;

if($_REQUEST['empid']) 
    {
        $sql = "SELECT id, employee_name, employee_salary, employee_age FROM    employee WHERE id='".$_REQUEST['empid']."'";
        $resultset = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("database error:". mysqli_error($conn));
        $data = array();

        while( $rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultset) ) 
            {
                $data = $rows;
            }
            echo json_encode($data);
    } 
else 
    {
        echo 0;
        $_SESSION['Fail'] = true;
    }

?>>
```

My sessionHandler is used to achieve the database connection and session verification.

I followed along with the tutorial. And thus far my system will:

-Retrieve the users from the table.

-Populate the drop down with them.

-Allow me to select a user.

-Display $_SESSION['PopulateWorking'] as 'true'

AND

-Properly read through employee data while I watch it in JS debugger.

But somewhere along these lines I am missing something. I have worked with AJAX, PHP, and SQL pretty frequently. But am by no means an expert. I am looking for where I am missing an integral step? I just want to try and display the data like he does in the tutorial. Because then I can fine tune and change everything around to make it work how I would like. But right now when I click a user nothing populates on the page like it does in his tutorial. Mine works right up until the actual important part. Displaying the selected data.

When compared next to his mine also does not display : "Please select employee name to view details", anywhere on the page? So I am thinking I am missing an entire DIV somewhere? Or not generating it? Or the script is not calling it properly?

I just can't seem to figure out where I am incorrectly utilizing the JSON data?

TL;DR: Why will my page not display the result data on my page like it does in this tutorial?

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input, especially that which comes from the client side. Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: I strongly advice you to stop following this tutorial! It is teaching you very wrong PHP coding practices.

Comment: @Dharman oh no! i was just trying to find a way to display my SQL data into a dropdown list. Is it really that bad? Honestly i just wanted to display table data into a list from SQL using AJAX. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: @Morjee, you need to listen to the advice of Dharman. The code is sql injection vulnerable. You are passing  parameters/request directly into the sql queries without prior escape, validation and sanitization

Answer (score 0):

Im sorry for the waste of time. I did not have any of the div's that i was trying to reference in popJax.php

I needed to add